# Spotify stops playing when launching my Ionic App

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, spotify

I am building an alarm ionic app that load custom sounds according to my preference and using the NativeAudio component.

The alarm is intended to just give me a buzz on specific times playing some voice recorded reminders. So when I listen to spotify and the alarm fires, it should put spotify music on hold and plays it back after the alarm.

I know we cannot control the spotify app from an outside app. However, I noticed that when I video in facebook, spotify stops, and after the video, spotify resumes.

Any guide on how to do an ionic app with this behavior would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus.html) on developer.android.com: there is a parameter named `AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK` which may be worth exploring. (Unfortunately I don't know much about Ionic but there should be some means of requesting audio focus with this parameter)

Comment: Thanks for this. Decided to drop the approach altogether. Your input is much appreciated.